# How to find two different class names using find_elements_by_css_selector

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to find an answer for this on the net.

Here's a snippet of html code:

```
<td>
    <div class="low-fare-day active"></div>
    <div class="low-prices"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="low-fare-day"></div>
    <div class="low-prices1"></div>
</td>
```

Below is my code:

I want to find the two classes low-fare-day and low-fare-day.active using css_selector, but couldn't get it working. Can anyone solve this puzzle for me?

fromdata = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.low-fare-day','div.low-fare-day.active')

or

fromdata = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.low-fare-day' | 'div.low-fare-day.active')

Comment: Do you mean elements that match both classes, or either? If both, `div.low-fare-day.active` should work as the selector.

Comment: yes, i need to match both classes. div.low-fare-day.active only returns the first prize 'low-prices'. does the second class "low-fare-day " having a blank space behind causing it to return only the first prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class*=low-fare-day]')
```

Explanation:

> **div**[class*=low-fare-day] -> means you're looking for a div
>
> div[**class***=low-fare-day] -> you're selecting the class value inside the div selected before to compare values
>
> ***=** after class means you will cath all that is equals or that contains the next value
>
> div[class*=**low-fare-day**] -> the value to compare if the div's class contains it